# pagetotal does not reset after page break

Tags: page-breaking, page, dimensions

Consider this example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \section{1}
        \lipsum[1-4]
        \the\pagetotal

\end{document}
```

The last page shows

[image]

The `pagetotal` value is clearly not the total vertical space used in the page, which is only one line.

What is the problem here?

Comment: In your example, `\the\pagetotal` is part of the last lipsum paragraph. To better see the effects of the delayed page break and thus of paragraphs needed for updating `\pagetotal` (see link), you can add `\par\thepagetotal\par\thepagetotal` once before `\end{document}`.